# How to center responsive grid

Tags: css, web, grid, center, responsive

I am trying to build a page with a grid of images (all 300px by 300px).
When resizing: the image size does not change, but the extra image on each row gets dropped down to the row below.

What I have now on JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/xixi/w4xx9y33/

It is working mostly fine, but I would really like to make the grid centered at all times,  instead of left aligned. Like the pin grid on Pinterest.com

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
    <div class="grid_item"><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhuivuugas64swf/test.jpg?dl=0"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
.grid_item {
    @include rowMachine(1, 10%);
    display: inline-block;
    background: none;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;

    @media (min-width: 500px) {
        @include rowMachine(2, 5%);
        float: left;
    }
...
```

Leave the rest as it is.

NB: If you need IE7 support, you might have an issue with inline-block on a block.

Comment: Seems to be centered here : https://jsfiddle.net/w4xx9y33/4/
Otherwise I suggest you use a CSS framework, like Bootstrap or Foundation. Would be easier for you to manage your responsive grid. http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably use flexbox technique to achieve what you want.

Check the below reference pages

http://www.sitepoint.com/using-modern-css-to-build-a-responsive-image-grid/

https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: hi ShanthoshK, in both of the examples the images resize as the window resizes -  that is not the behavior I am looking for. Also in neither examples, the grid is centered. They are both left aligned.

Comment: Both Bootstrap and Zurb foundation latest versions uses FlexBox technique I guess. I have suggested the emerging simple CSS technique to avoid a CSS framework for a small need. It is up to you.